# Why is computed style in mobile safari differing from ruled style?

Tags: ios, html, css

I have an iframe inside a popup for some reason in mobile safari once the iframe loads it's changing the size of the iframe to go beyond the screen dimensions and no matter what I do in inspector the computed style won't update.

The style that inspector shows is taking effect is (and works everywhere else including android):

```
.gc-lightbox > iframe {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 645px;
    width: 900px;
    position: relative;
    border: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
}
```

However, in mobile safari the "computed height" and "computed width" are way off (depending on which popup you initiate) they're up as high as 3000px tall and 700px wide. Inspector does not have the `height: 900px` or the `max-height: 90%` crossed out and even if I put `style="width: 300px !important; height: 300px !important"` directly on the iframe tag the computed values are still going past these values with no indication as to why.

Any clues?

Click on any of the campus tour links (as I said, it works as expected everywhere but mobile safari - even android)
http://www.georgiancollege.ca/new-campus-tours/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my projects, Safari Computed Rules were not matching the Styles Rules. And like, you even adding !important directly to the inline style did not help.

The culprit turned out to be too many transition effects on the page. The transitions were on inputs and textareas (which we manipulated a lot with JS). Changing to this helped me out.

```
  transition: none;
```

Comment: That ended up being the same thing on mine. Forgot to come back and add that.